# Get sum of record attributes when grouping in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, group-by, sum

I am grouping mileage entries by month in my Rails 3.2 application:

**mileages_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @mileages = Mileage.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @mileages_months = Mileage.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id).group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @mileages }
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @mileages_months.sort.each do |month, mileages| %>
  <h4><%= month.strftime('%B %Y') %></h4>
  <p>Total miles <strong><%= mileages.miles.sum %></strong>.</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Miles</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
      <% for mileage in mileages %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= mileage.name %></td>
          <td><%= mileage.miles %></td>
          <td><%= mileage.start %></td>
          <td><%= mileage.end %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', mileage %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I am trying to sum the total miles in each month using `<%= mileages.miles.sum %>`. This won't work - but `<%= mileages.first.miles %>` correctly shows the first entry's miles for each month.

What is the correct way of totalling up the miles column for each month?

Comment: what does your mileage model consist of, ie attributes ?

Comment: @total_mileage = @mileages_months.sum(:miles)  this is an assumption but notice how to pass the attribute you want

Comment: @Richlewis it consists of `miles`,`date`,`start`,`end` and `name`.

Comment: @Richlewis `@total_mileage = @mileages_months.sum(:miles)` seems to return an array of each entry.

Comment: @total_mileage = @mileages.calculate(:sum, "mileage.start + mileage.end")

Comment: are you using devise as you could do this @total_mileage = current_user.calculate(:sum, "mileage.start + mileage.end") this is only off the top of my head though

Comment: @Richlewis The start and end are for location, the miles attribute is the decimal value.

Comment: oh ok, so what about @total_mileage = @mileages.sum(:miles) are you using Devise?

Comment: @Richlewis That returns `undefined method `+' for #<Mileage:0x007fb1c97654a8>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create a helper method(to keep this logic seperate from the view) in the `mileage_helper` as :

```
def sum_mileges(mileages)
  mileages.map(&:miles).sum
end
```

and then calling it in the view as

```
<p>Total miles <strong><%= sum_mileges(mileages) %></strong>.</p>
```

OR

you can do it directly as :

```
<p>Total miles <strong><%= mileages.map(&:miles).sum %></strong>.</p>
```